# I have 5 ip's from my ISP, How do I browse and use them all?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, google-chrome, ip

I want to be able to open chrome/chromium and firefox at the same time, but have each be seen from different ip addresses. If I were to do a google search for "what is my ip" in chrome, it should give me ip.ip.ip.1 and then firefox could give me ip.ip.ip.2.

How could I accomplish this? I'm using ubuntu 14.04 64 bit

Comment: Sorry, that’s not how it works. it is possible to have 5 nics, each with one address, and to bind applications to use a specific nic if the application supports it, but I do not believe you will achieve what you want in that manner.

Comment: You are paying for 5 IPs to use on one machine?

Comment: business account, so they throw in 5 ip's. I'd like to utilize them if I can.

Answer (score 3):

As @Frank Thomas mentioned in his comment, Chrome and Firefox probably don't support this scenario natively, however it shouldn't be too hard to get it to work.  You can assign your NIC multiple IP addresses, however the browsers are not going to bind specific IP, they will end up just using the default IP/route.

To get one browser to use a non-default IP, I would setup a lightweight proxy server on the same machine.  Most proxy servers should support binding to a specific IP, you can then setup the second browser to use the proxy server and traffic should emerge from that IP.

Comment: IPtables can differentiate traffic made by different users, so it should be possible to run multiple instances of the browser as different users (using `su`) and then use some IPtables magic to modify the source address of packets and achieve what you want.